# Add column headers to a very large csv doc

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv doc with hundreds of columns. I want to add a row at the top with headers  f1,f2,f3,f4.....fn to give a name to each column

How is it possible to do that automatically with excel?

Comment: Record a macro while opening the file in excel, inserting a row, adding the headers, then saving and closing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right-click the Row 1 label, select Insert.  That will create a new blank row.
2. Type "f1" to A1 and "f2" into A2.
3. Highlight those two cells.
4. Left-click and hold the small square in the lower-right of the selection rectangle.
5. Drag that square to the right.  Excel will auto-increment the number.

[image: Location of drag point]

Drag across...

[image: Drag to right image]

Release...

[image: image of auto-numbered headers]